# when i enter password the first alphabet comes different not what i have entered

Tags: c++

this is the code for accepting a string and display '*' at each place of alphabet(for password).For example i have entered password than it shows @assword instead of password when i cout the string.please help me.....

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
clrscr();
char pass[5];

cout<<"\n\n Pass : ";
int i=0;
pass[0]=getch();
while(pass[i]!=13)
{        i++;
    cout<<"*";
    pass[i]=getch();

}

cout<<"\n\n";

cout<<pass;

getch();
}
```

Comment: That's not quite what he is doing - he is reading until a `\n`; but the allocation is indeed wrong.

Comment: I take that back. Is there a season you allocate 5 characters for a password, but enter more then that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've only allocated 5 bytes for the password, but read an arbitary number of bytes, which will lead to illegal accesses and basically all sorts of (potentially) random stuff happening, including odd corruptions like you have seen.

Also, you fail to null terminate your char array, so you might get random stuff printed after the password - a `pass[++i]='\0';` placed after the loop will fix that.

Try increasing it to a much larger value and see if that fixes the issue.
If not, can you paste the entire output - do the * get messed up? is it just the